# Order-preserving image of a complete lattice

Tags: order-theory, lattice-theory

If $L$ is a complete lattice and $P$ is a poset and $f: L\to P$ is an order preserving surjective map, does this imply that $P$ is a (complete) lattice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily - there is even a finite counterexample.

Let $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and set $L := \mathcal{P}(X)$.

Let $P := \{b, t\} \cup \{(i,j): i,j \in \{0,1\}\}$, where $b$ will be the botton (least) element, $t$ is the top (greatest) element, and $\{(i,j): i,j \in \{0,1\}\}$ is ordered by $$(i, j) < (k, l) \text{  if and only if } i = 0 \text{ and } k = 1.$$ So $P$ is not a lattice, as $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ do not have a least upper bound.

As for the surjection $f: \mathcal{P}(X) \to P$, set $\emptyset \mapsto b$, $X\mapsto t$, and moreover $\{1\} \mapsto (0,0)$ and $\{2\},\{3\}\mapsto (0,1)$ and $X\setminus \{1\} \mapsto (1,0)$ and the rest maps to $(1,1)$.

It's a routine verification that $f$ is onto and order-preserving.

Answer (score 3):

No, clearly not, because you could put junk on top.

But even if you avoid this by insisting that the map is surjective, there are counterexamples. Consider the map of [Eric Wofsey's recent answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/194954/1946), where he considered the partial order $L(X)$, where $X$ is an antichain of pairwise incomparable elements, and we add $0$ and $1$ to bound it. This is a complete lattice, and it admits an order preserving surjection to any bounded partial order on $X$. Such an order may not be a complete lattice, and so this provides numerous counterexamples.

Comment: The same shows that $f$ can even be *bijective*, where it would be the same type of thing as often occurs in topology: a map which is an isomorphism at the level of sets but far from an isomorphism at the level of the structure considered.